# Odious twin locations related to the sequence based on $d(n) = n-d(d(n-1))-d(d(n-2))$

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, recurrences

Let $\operatorname{wt}(n)$ be [A000120](https://oeis.org/A000120), i.e. the number of $1$'s in binary expansion of $n$ (or the binary weight of $n$).

Let $a(n)$ be the sequence of numbers $k$ such that $\operatorname{wt}(k)\operatorname{mod}2=\operatorname{wt}(k+1)\operatorname{mod}2=1$: the sequence begins with
$$1, 7, 13, 21, 25, 31, 37, 41, 49, 55, 61, 69, 73, 81, 87, 93, 97, 103, 109, 117$$

Here $a(n)$ is [A157971](https://oeis.org/A157971), odious twin locations: first members of pairs of consecutive odious numbers.

Let $b(n)=\frac{a(n)-1}{2}$.

Let $c(n)$ be the sequence of numbers $\frac{b(k)}{3}$ such that $3|b(k)$: the sequence begins with

$$1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 16, 17, 18, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25, 26, 30, 32$$

**Conjecture**: $c(n)$ is [A095775](https://oeis.org/A095775), $\frac{n}{2}$ when $2$[A003160](https://oeis.org/A003160)$(n) = n$.

Here [A003160](https://oeis.org/A003160) is
$$d(n) = n-d(d(n-1))-d(d(n-2)), d(1) = d(2) = 1$$

Is there a way to prove it?